# Spriteheet image loading not working as expected

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I am going to explain the problem as good as possible.

I have made a HTML5 game for a school assignment and cannot fix some problems in it. The game is working but i'd like to make the coder more slick.

on the index.html i have the following img tag:

```
<img src="images/bart.png">
```

It needs to be loaded else the game will not play and i don't know why because in the player.js file i also have the image loaded in my spritesheet.

```
var sprite = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
            "framerate": 24,
            "images": ["images/bart.png"],
            "frames": {
                "height": 81,
                "count": 6,
                "regX": 23,
                "regY": 0,
                "width": 47
            }
```

on my game.js the image also gets removed on the frontpage else it will stay on the homepage and does not look nice.

```
     // verwijder spritesheet speler
        $('img[src$="bart.png"]').remove();
```

To make things look more clear i give you my URL so you can look up all code as i may be missing some important stuff. http://bartnooijens.nl/school/creativeprogramming/

What I am really asking is the following: How can i remove the image on the index.html and my game will still run because when i remove it now on the index.html my game will not run.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a sample? If you use a SpriteSheet with a string image path (like your sample), then it will automatically load it for you -- *but* you need to ensure the stage is updated after the load completes. If you just generate the Sprite and update the stage once, it may not display.

Comment: Hello Lanny, thanks for answering my post. What do you mean with a sample? My complete code could be checked at the url i gave above (http://bartnooijens.nl/school/creativeprogramming/). Maybe i did not explain it in a good way but i only want to remove the image path on the index.html and want the spritesheet still to be loaded, but i don't know what to do for it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link.  You don't need the image in the index at all, as I mentioned, the SpriteSheet will automatically create and load an image in the background if you pass a string path. For better preloading, have a look at PreloadJS, which has SpriteSheet loading support in 0.6.1+

Comment: One note: Your stage update should be the last thing you do in your `tick()`, otherwise your contents that you update in that method will be 1 frame ahead of what is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. I get the note, thanks for the tip! But the image loading thing I still don't get. What you say is:i can remove the image from the index and it should still work fine because i load it in at the spritesheet i make?

Comment: Correct, the SpriteSheet images will load once you create a Sprite.

Comment: But do i need to change something in my code? That's basiacly the whole question i have since i don't know what i need to change :)

Comment: I am suggesting that including the image tag in the HTML is unnecessary, and you can remove it. Creating the Sprite will load the image if you pass a string path (you can also pass a reference to an image instead). It will not display in the Stage until it is loaded, so you may have to update the stage.

Comment: so i need to remove `<img src="images/bart.png">` from the index.html and also remove `$('img[src$="bart.png"]').remove();` from spel.js as it removed the image from the index.html but what do i need to do next? can you help me out a bit because i tried some things but i just don't know what i need to change. Thanks!